# Multithreading in divide and conquer matrix multiplication

Tags: multithreading, performance, matrix-multiplication, divide-and-conquer

There is [this](http://codebeautify.org/javaviewer/cbc22629) code of divide and conquer matrix multiplication which is taking quite a lot of time for the operations, when the input size for the matrix is nearly 4k. **Multi-threading** can be considered as a solution for reducing the running time. But should we create Thread as a object and pass or just implement a Runnable class? both the perspective seem to be working but when we create a thread more than a particular number the running time seems to be more worse.

Please some explain why is it so with an implementation of the same in java or python?

Comment: Using too many threads never works well. Also, this code has significant opportunity for optimization by making it more efficient (as opposed to burning more polar bears) - you don't have to put a submatrix in its own "physical" matrix and you can materialize results directly into the final matrix.

Comment: harold, I tried doing it using 15 threads(which I thought was optimal) and this benefited me by only a couple of seconds.

Will you please demonstrate this by implementing? 

Also please tell me what are opportunities of optimization, memoization?

Thanks..

Comment: haha, Sunny, you want us to demonstrate this by implementing?  I charge $80 per hour.

Comment: Mike I have already implemented, but that is taking a lot of time, will you suggest edits in that?

Comment: @Sunny the first one is probably simplest: represent a submatrix as a window into the original matrix instead of copying them to new arrays. Saves lots of copying.